# Tengo una consulta que devuelve varios registros por empleado. Pero solo quiero un registro por empleado con la ultima fecha de ingreso

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Quiero seleccionar la lista de empleados, pero solo un registro por empleado con la ultima fecha de ingreso incluido el cargo relacionado a ese ingreso. Adjunto diagrama de las tablas relacionas en la consulta.

Es decir una persona puede ingresar a la empresa en varios oportunidades. Durante esos ingresos puede ingresar a otro cargo en otra area.

```
SELECT tblEmpleado.id,
tblEmpleado.numero_identificacion as cedula,
tblEmpleado.idTipo_Documento as id_tipodoc,
tblTipo_Documento.descripcion,
tblEmpleado.nombre,
tblEmpleado.apellidos,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),tblEmpleado.fecha_nacimiento) as fecha_nacimiento,
tblEmpleado.edad,
tblEmpleado.telefono, 
tblEmpleado.direccion,
tblEmpleado.Id_Municipio as id_muni,
tblMunicipio.descripcion AS municipio,
tblEmpleado.correo,
tblEmpleado.idTipo_Contrato as id_Contra,
tblTipo_Contrato.descripcion AS contrato,
tblEmpleado.idUbicacion as id_ubicacion, 
tblUbicacion.Descripcion AS ubicacion,
tblEmpleado.idSexo as id_sexo,
tblSexo.descripcion AS sexo,
tblEmpleado.salario,
tblAFPEmpleado.Fecha_Afiliacion as fecha_afp,
tblAFP.id AS id_afp,
tblAFP.Descripcion AS afp,
tblEPSEmpleado.Fecha_Afiliacion AS fecha_eps, 
tblEPS.id AS id_eps,
tblEPS.descripcion AS eps,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),tblIngresoCargo.fecha_ingreso) as fecha_ingreso,
tblCargo.id as id_cargo,
tblCargo.descripcion AS cargo,
tblArea.id AS id_area,
tblArea.descripcion AS area,
tblOperacion.id AS id_ope, 
tblOperacion.descripcion AS operacion,
tblEmpleado.activo
FROM    tblCargo INNER JOIN
tblArea ON tblCargo.id_area = tblArea.id INNER JOIN
tblOperacion ON tblArea.id_operacion = tblOperacion.id INNER JOIN
tblIngresoCargo ON tblCargo.id = tblIngresoCargo.IdCargo INNER JOIN
tblTipo_Documento INNER JOIN
tblTipo_Contrato INNER JOIN
tblSexo INNER JOIN
tblEmpleado ON tblSexo.idSexo = tblEmpleado.idSexo INNER JOIN
tblEPS INNER JOIN
tblEPSEmpleado ON tblEPS.id = tblEPSEmpleado.idEPS ON tblEmpleado.id = tblEPSEmpleado.idEmpleado INNER JOIN
tblAFP INNER JOIN
tblAFPEmpleado ON tblAFP.id = tblAFPEmpleado.idAFP ON tblEmpleado.id = tblAFPEmpleado.idEmpleado INNER JOIN
tblMunicipio ON tblEmpleado.Id_Municipio = tblMunicipio.id ON tblTipo_Contrato.id = tblEmpleado.idTipo_Contrato ON tblTipo_Documento.id = tblEmpleado.idTipo_Documento INNER JOIN
tblUbicacion ON tblEmpleado.idUbicacion = tblUbicacion.id ON tblIngresoCargo.IdEmpleado = tblEmpleado.id
```

[image: Adjunto Diagrama de SQLSERVER para el problma a solucionar]

Comment: ¿Querés agrupar la consulta por fecha de ingreso en cada sector? Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Pasa en en la tabla ingresoCargo, un empleado puede tener varios registros, porque puede salir y entrar de la empresa en repetidas ocaciones a los largo de los años. Ahora al momento de listar empleados con sus respectivos cargos me sale cada registro de ingreso y salida un trabajador. Quisiera realizar la consulta y que solo me  traiga el ultimo ingresoCargo, es decir el ingreso con fecha mas reciente si es que tiene varios.

Comment: ¿Y ya lo intentaste con `MAX`?